# How to send ATQA and SEL to Mifare Classic 1k

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare

According to the documentation, before a read/write can occur, I need to send REQA followed by SELECT for anti-collision.
But I couldn't find any complete example code, code sequence performing this.
Every one starts with `authenticate` in `onTagDiscovered`, and starts reading/writing.

So my question is, 
1. does Android performs its own REQA/SEL on its own under the hood?
2. If i wanted to, how do I perform REQA and SEL on my own?

I have come up with a sample code, based on the code [here](https://github.com/pkourany/MFRC522_RFID_Library/blob/9b5e5fde852576ba3187cd6e1e575d1b9e72e801/src/MFRC522.cpp#L467)

```
try {
            byte[] reqa = new byte[1];
            reqa[0] = 0x26;
            Log.e(TAG, "Sending REQA: " + bytesToHex(reqa));
            mifareTag.transceive(reqa);                
            Log.e(TAG, bytesToHex(mifareTag.transceive(reqa)));

            byte[] sel = new byte[9];
            sel[0] = (byte) 0x93;
            sel[1] = (byte) 0x70;
            System.arraycopy(uid, uid.length - 4, sel, 2, 4);
            sel[6] = (byte) (sel[2] ^ sel[3] ^ sel[4] ^ sel[5]);

            java.util.zip.CRC32 x = new java.util.zip.CRC32();
            x.update(sel);
            long crc32 = x.getValue();

            sel[7] = (byte) crc32;
            sel[8] = (byte) (crc32 >> 8);

            Log.e(TAG, "CRC: " + Long.toHexString(crc32));
            Log.e(TAG, "Sending SEL: " + bytesToHex(sel));

            Log.e(TAG, bytesToHex(mifareTag.transceive(sel)));
            if (mifareTag.transceive(cmd) != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "NfcA Tag transcieve:auth success");
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "NfcA Tag transcieve:auth failed with exception !", ex);
            return false;
        }
```

But the problem is, with this code, what I'm receiving back is weird data.

```
10-22 11:04:13.465 30687-30734/com.mfreader E/RfidReader: Sending REQA: 26
10-22 11:04:13.492 30687-30734/com.mfreader E/RfidReader: B2007D9BD20804000215671E0D8B811D
10-22 11:04:13.492 30687-30734/com.mfreader E/RfidReader: CRC: a247ff86
10-22 11:04:13.493 30687-30734/com.mfreader E/RfidReader: Sending SEL: 93701A2E7D9BD286FF
10-22 11:04:13.519 30687-30734/com.mfreader E/RfidReader: B2007D9BD20804000215671E0D8B811D
10-22 11:04:13.602 30687-30734/com.mfreader E/RfidReader: NfcA Tag transcieve:auth failed with exception !
    java.io.IOException: Transceive failed
        at android.nfc.TransceiveResult.getResponseOrThrow(TransceiveResult.java:52)
        at android.nfc.tech.BasicTagTechnology.transceive(BasicTagTechnology.java:151)
        at android.nfc.tech.NfcA.transceive(NfcA.java:145)
```

The returned value is `Sect#0Block#0` but the first 2 bytes replaced with `B200` instead of `1A2E` of the UID. And the succeeding Auth fails, which otherwise fails only intermittently (which is what i'm trying to solve)!

Not sure what i'm doing wrong, any help?

Comment: Well, even though the tag is still not responding correctly to my raw requests (it does with Android though!), what i have figured out is, the CRC calculation is different, its not CRC32, its CRC16 with specific polynomials. More details here https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/blob/bf31594410e18b7761d5536d692ea6762871e833/libnfc/iso14443-subr.c#L48

Answer (score 0):

> 1. does Android performs its own REQA/SEL on its own under the hood?

Yes

> 2. If I wanted to, how do I perform REQA and SEL on my own?

```
  /**
 * Send raw NFC-A commands to the tag and receive the response.
 *
 * <p>Applications must not append the EoD (CRC) to the payload,
 * it will be automatically calculated.
 * <p>Applications must only send commands that are complete bytes,
 * for example a SENS_REQ is not possible (these are used to
 * manage tag polling and initialization).
 *
 * <p>Use {@link #getMaxTransceiveLength} to retrieve the maximum number of bytes
 * that can be sent with {@link #transceive}.
 *
 * <p>This is an I/O operation and will block until complete. It must
 * not be called from the main application thread. A blocked call will be canceled with
 * {@link IOException} if {@link #close} is called from another thread.
 *
 * <p class="note">Requires the {@link android.Manifest.permission#NFC} permission.
 *
 * @param data bytes to send
 * @return bytes received in response
 * @throws TagLostException if the tag leaves the field
 * @throws IOException if there is an I/O failure, or this operation is canceled
 */
public byte[] transceive(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    return transceive(data, true);
}
```

You can select tag by method `mifareTag.connect()`, after authenticating with android methods from android docs you can write and read. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic
What means error 'B2' do you got it somewhere in documentation?

Comment: do you have any documentation/source code link showing Android performing its own REQA/SEL during the handshake for NfcA tags?